# How to debug a server-side (.rdl) report that does not work in my application?

Tags: ssrs-2008, report, reportviewer, server-side

I have a SQL Server Report Server (SSRS) that hosts a bunch of reports. When I click on the provided URL, I can navigate to the report, drilling down the path, and I can successfully run the report by passing it the required parameters. The Stored Procedures used by the report are hosted in a database that uses Windows Authentication.

However, when I try to call the same report from my application, I cannot see anything.

Here is the code I use. Upon clicking on a button, I execute this code:

```
var reportViewer = new ReportViewer();

// Set Processing Mode
reportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;

// Set report server and report path
reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://MySsrsServer/reportserver");
reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/Reports/MyReport";

// set the credentials
reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials.ImpersonationUser = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();

// create report parameters and set them in the report
var param1 = new ReportParameter("First_Param", "Some string");
var param2 = new ReportParameter("Second_Param", "Some other string");
reportViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { param1, param2 });


using (var reportForm = new ReportForm(reportViewer))
{
   reportForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

The ReportForm is just a regular Form that has a member of type ReportViewer. In the class constructor I assign the member:

```
public ReportForm(ReportViewer reportViewer)
{
   InitializeComponent();

   try
   {
      this.reportViewer = reportViewer;

      reportViewer.SetDisplayMode(DisplayMode.PrintLayout);

      reportViewer.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

      reportViewer.ZoomMode = ZoomMode.Percent;
      reportViewer.ZoomPercent = 100;
      reportViewer.RefreshReport();
   }
   catch (Exception exception)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
   }
}
```

As I said, I can see the report being correctly executed from Server, but not from my application. The content of the ReportForm is empty, but I do not get any exceptions being thrown.

Any idea what is it I am doing wrong?

TIA,
E

Comment: Further to my question, using database tracing, we can confirm that the Stored Procedures used by the report are called with proper parameters and they return proper data.Why is then the report result shown blank? Is there a way to trace inside the Reporting server and see what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that constructing the ReportViewer object outside the form where the report is to be displayed and then passing it inside the constructor of the form in order to assign it to the inner ReportViewer object is not a good idea. I don't know what's happening behind the scene, perhaps some bindings between the ReportViewr instance and the GUI control that is to show the report are broken.